# Using DNS in URL of post Request get 401 - unauthorized but works fine if I use the actual server name in the URL

Tags: c#, .net, security, iis, windows-authentication

we call API from  controller-A (server-side) to controller-B

both are configured as sperated sites in **IIS**

**site of A  - security configuration:
**

```
<security>

      <authentication>

        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">

          <providers>

            <clear />

            <add value="NTLM" />

            <add value="Negotiate" />

          </providers>

        </windowsAuthentication>

        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />

      </authentication>

    </security>
```

**site of B  - security configuration:**

```
<security>

                     <authentication>

                           <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />

                           <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>

                           <basicAuthentication enabled="true"/>

                     </authentication>

</security>
```

request code here:
`

```
  HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
               Credentials = new CredentialCache() {
                    {
                        httpRequest.RequestUri,
                        "NTLM",
                        CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
                    } }
            };        

            var response = await new HttpClient(httpClientHandler).PostAsync(url, data);
```

`
when url is :
https://serverName.domain:4444/home/apiName -- all is fine

but when
https://VipName.domain:4444/home/apiName -- get 401

Thanks fo any help!!!

in IIS-log we can see the user not passed

Comment: Your network has one or more Password servers.  Probably one associated with each domain.  So I suspect the user credentials are in one domain and not the other.

Comment: for now , all servers in this problem scope are in the same domain

Comment: Then the Group Policy is different.  It is not your code.  Check with your IS.

Comment: I've encountered a similar error with you. 401-Unauthorized indicates that it lacks valid authentication credentials for the request. Enabling anonymousAuthentication  and choose Application pool identity in IIS worked for me. Hope it can also help you.

Answer (score 0):

For the browser to send the credentials, it has to be a trusted site. It's possible that "serverName.domain" is trusted, but "VipName.domain" is not.

Chrome and Edge use the Trusted Sites in Internet Options:

1. Windows key + R and run "inetcpl.cpl"
2. Click the 'Security' tab
3. Click 'Trusted Sites' then the 'Sites' button
4. Verify if "VipName.domain" is in the list and add it if not. You can use wildcards, like "https://*.domain"

Firefox has its own settings, which you can see here: https://superuser.com/a/878494/233663